# Highcharts plotband doesn't redraws properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

Im using the following code to redraw my plot band by clicking on button. Event happens only once and instead of permanently changing the region of plotband it jums for a second and then comes back to its original state.

```
var drugScatterPlot = function (ensemblID, drugName) {

var myData;



$.get("./php/drugActivityJSON.php", {
        ensemblID: ensemblID,
        drugName: drugName
    },
    function (data) {
        myData = JSON.parse(data);

        $(function () {
            $('#scatterPlot').highcharts({

                plotOptions: {

                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        events: {
                            click: function (event) {
                                // alert(this.name + ' clicked\n' +
                                //     'Alt: ' + event.altKey + '\n' +
                                //     'Control: ' + event.ctrlKey + '\n' +
                                //     'Shift: ' + event.shiftKey + '\n');

                                highlightResidueByID(ensemblID, currentPDBID, currentChainID, event.point.x);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },


                tooltip: {
                    backgroundColor: '#AAAAAA',
                    borderColor: 'black',
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    borderWidth: 3
                },

                chart: {
                    type: 'scatter'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },

                xAxis: {



                    plotLines: [{
                            color: 'red', // Color value
                            dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                            value: 400, // Value of where the line will appear
                            width: 3, // Width of the line 
                            id: "plot-line-1"

                            },
                        {
                            color: 'red', // Color value
                            dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                            value: 600, // Value of where the line will appear
                            width: 3, // Width of the line 
                            id: "plot-line-2"

                            }
                            ],

                    plotBands: [{
                        color: '#EEEEEE', // Color value
                        from: 400, // Start of the plot band
                        to: 600, // End of the plot band
                        id: "plot-band-1"
                        }],


                },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Activity area'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Residue Value',
                    data: myData
                    }]

            });


            /* -------------------BUTTON ACTION ------------------------------*/


            var chart = $('#scatterPlot').highcharts(),
                $button = $('.ENSEMBLDomain');

            $button.click(function () {

                chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
                chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1');
                chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-2');

                chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
                    from: 200,
                    to: 300,
                    color: '#EEEEEE',
                    id: 'plot-band-1'
                });

                chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                    value: 200,
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 2,
                    dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
                    id: 'plot-line-1'
                });

                chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                    value: 300,
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 2,
                    dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
                    id: 'plot-line-2'
                });



            });






        });



    });
```

};

Comment: Im not clicking some unknown link just so I can do your debugging work for you.

Comment: what would be the best way to people to look at my code and figure out what's going on?

Comment: Post the relevant code here. Make sure its only what you need to represent the problem - we don't want to dig through tons of lines of irrelevant code. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For me, your code works fine - when clicking on "Region annotations" I see redraw on the chart with proper plot band. However I can see errors in the console `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` in line: `chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');`.